# Dividing a graph into 2 disconnected subgraphs

Tags: python, matrix, graph

I'm trying to find an algorithm that shows is it possible to divide a graph into two sub_graphs  and my input is the Adjacency matrix of the graph.
And my language is python but it isn't so important and the algorithm is important.
thanks for your helps :)

Comment: See [Where should I post questions about algorithms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se)

Comment: Can you modify the graph, or is it that you want to show there are two disconnected graphs.

Comment: @Peter Wood No I can't modify the graph

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134956/determinants-in-graph-theory

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem

Comment: @PeterWood thanks peter (: